# When i added my app_name into the app/urls.py the page showing not correct

Tags: django

i am getting not right path after adding ap_name in my app/urls.py
what is going wrong i dont know i

app/urls.py--->>

from django.urls import path

from . import views

```
        app_name = 'blog'

         urlpatterns = [

             path('', views.home_page, name = "home"),
             path('about/', views.about_page, name = "about"),
             path('contact/', views.contact_page, name = "contact"),
             path('products/<int:page_id>/', views.product_details, name = "products"),
             path('add-product/', views.create_product_page, name = "create_product"),
             path('update-product/', views.update_product_page, name = "update_product"),
             path('delate-product/', views.contact_page, name = "delete_product"),


            ]
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not the right path". Can you show the error/wrong output? What is the expected output?

Comment: How you use url name in template?

Comment: <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>

Answer (score 0):

You are calling it in wrong way 
 to go to Blog app url you have to call it in this way

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'blog:home' %}">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass the namespace if you want to call the home url you have to include the namespace

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'blog:home' %}">Home</a>
```